# Java incremented object names

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My current issue that I am overwriting my cell object. Since I cannot do `("cell" + i)`, how would I be able to do this?

```
public void printMonthCounts(int cellMonthPosition, String month) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {//11 countrys
            Row row = sheet2.createRow(7 + i);//Starts with Gb
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellMonthPos);//Month position

            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    cell.setCellValue(countryHash.get(month).getGb());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cell.setCellValue(countryHash.get(month).getPt());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cell.setCellValue(countryHash.get(month).getEs());
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I am using Apache POI for excel, but I know this to be a general Java 'thing', I am beginner in Java.

How can I have an incremented object names?

*The switch case is longer but I shortened it for this example.

Comment: I would suggest putting the strings in an array and loop over the array. Like Something like: `Country c = countryHash.get(month); String[] values = { c.getGb(), c.getPt(), c.getEs() }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got this right, you want to dynamically create object names? Long story short, you can't. The usual way to do this is to use an array: instead of trying to create `n` objects called `cell1, cell2, etc` just create an array of cells and create each object at the `ith` position of your array.

Comment: Well I guess you're right, I'll correct it. English is not my native language so I lack some of its subtleties.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try creating an array and increment the index using a loop

Answer (score 0):

you can do that, if I am getting your question right, by setting  a temporary string that holds the string plus the incremented number. After that, you can name your object with the temporary  string.

As in my situation,

```
temp = "row" + String.valueOf(k); //k is incremented int
    temp2 = temp; //I stored the value of temp because it changes to obj
    Row temp = new Row();
    temp.setNamel(temp2);//this is a method in my class Row to set name
    temp.setClientName((String)nameField.getText());
    k++;
    System.out.println(temp.getClientName());
    System.out.println(temp.getID());
    System.out.println(temp.getNamel());//to return the name of object
```

Output:

```
John
0
row0
```